# Mysql insert into a table using values from the same table with increment of one in coloum

Tags: mysql

I have a Table ABC

```
   ID    no         no2       no3     no4

    1     1         Abc       P       P
    2     2         xyz       A       P
    3     3         xsc       A       A
    4     4         xcs       P       P
```

i want to insert in ABC table

my query is like this

insert into ABC (no,no1,no2,no3,no4) values ((select max(no) from ABC + 1),'XXX','XXX1','XXXX2')

Comment: you want the 'no' column to be an ever-increasing sequence? you can try the [AUTO_INCREMENT column](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-sequences.htm) for this usecase..

Comment: i all ready have a auto increment coloum

Comment: ID and 'no' seems the same, no ?

Comment: whats the issue?

Comment: Coloum ID Is tha auto increment coloum but Coloum " NO" is not

Comment: I'm also missing how "ID" is distinct from "no1". Can you explain?

Comment: coloum "ID " is a sr. no. which is auto increment  and coloum "NO" is a bill no. which can be delected  and rearranged by the user  so if any one can delete bill no ,then it can be check by Sr.no that how many bill is deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the INSERT statement like:

```
insert into ABC (no,no2,no3,no4) select max(no)+ 1,'XXX','XXX1','XXXX2' from ABC;
```

## Example:

```
mysql> create table ABC(id int primary key auto_increment,no int, no2 varchar(20),no3 varchar(20),no4 varchar(20));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.46 sec)

mysql> insert into ABC values
    -> (1,1,'Abc','P','P'),
    -> (2,2,'xyz','A','P'),
    -> (3,3,'xsc','A','A'),
    -> (4,4,'xcs','P','P');
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.18 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> insert into ABC (no,no2,no3,no4) select max(no)+ 1,'XXX','XXX1','XXXX2' from ABC;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.16 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from ABC;
+----+------+------+------+-------+
| id | no   | no2  | no3  | no4   |
+----+------+------+------+-------+
|  1 |    1 | Abc  | P    | P     |
|  2 |    2 | xyz  | A    | P     |
|  3 |    3 | xsc  | A    | A     |
|  4 |    4 | xcs  | P    | P     |
|  5 |    5 | XXX  | XXX1 | XXXX2 |
+----+------+------+------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```